# How do I get a random number on the binance chain in solidity?

Tags: solidity, binance

How can I get a random number on binance smart chain in a solidity contract?

I am seeing these articles from binance about chainlink:
https://www.binance.com/en/blog/421499824684901349/New-on-Binance-Smart-Chain-Chainlink-Oracles

And Fetch AI
https://medium.com/fetch-ai/launching-our-random-number-beacon-on-binance-smart-chain-8e3b7aa52be6

But for the life of me I cannot find any documentation of how to use these on the production chain and how much the costs are.

Can anyone shed more light?

Chainlink has this article, but it only talks about testnet not production.
https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number

For Fetch-ai, google search returns article after article about the GLOW-DRB, but I cannot find anywhere how to use it. Cannot see anywhere in the Fetch-ai Github or on their developer documentation.

Also really want to know the costs.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Can you explain your difficulties adapting the Chainlink docs from their testnet to BSC?

Comment: If it is only available in testnet i do not want to use it as i do not know when it will be available in production. i cannot find any info about using it in production or any examples. thus i want to focus on a product that is already production ready so I don't encounter delays.

Comment: Looking at the example `fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network)` and given LINK is $24 at the time of writing then getting one random number would cost $2.4, which seems unviable expensive so not sure if I understood correctly